# When I add a function inside of my JavaScript fetch call it it is saying the function is not defined

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a JavaScript fetch call and trying to add a function called displayMenuOverlay inside of it. When I do so and trigger the function, by clicking, it says function not defined. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
 const url = 'https://localhost/nav.json';
    fetch(url).then(function(res) {
       return res.json();
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        document.querySelector('#nav_items').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
        document.querySelector(".mega-main-menu__logo").innerHTML = '<img src="https://example.com' + data.Image.Src + '" />';
        var numOfItems = data.Items.length;
        document.querySelector(".mega-main-menu__items").innerHTML = "";

        for(x = 0; x < numOfItems; x++){
            document.querySelector(".mega-main-menu__items").innerHTML +=
                "<li id='menu-item-" + x + "' onClick='displayMenuOverlay(" + x + ");' style='touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);'>"
                + data.Items[x].Title +
                    "<span class='fa fa-chevron-down'>" + "</span>" +
                "</li>"
            + "<div class='mega-menu-overlay' style='top:78px;'>" + "<div class='mega-menu-overlay__menu-container'>"
                + "<h4 class='mega-menu-overlay__title text-primary'>"
                + "<strong> " + data.Items[x].Title + " </strong>" +
                "</h4>" +
                    "</div>" +  "</div>" +
                "<div class='mega-menu-overlay__content'></div>";
        }
        function displayMenuOverlay(x)
        {
            var megaMenuContent = document.querySelector(".mega-menu-overlay__content");
            megaMenuContent.innerHTML = "";
            for(x=0; x < data.Items[x].Children.length; x++)
            {
                megaMenuContent.innerHTML += data.Items[x].Children.Title;
            }
        }

    }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: Because `onclick` functions must be available in global window namespace. You are declaring it inside another function and it is only scoped in that function and not available outside it

Comment: Inline event listeners are outdated practice. Start using modern unobtrusive methods for attaching event listeners and you won't have to pollute the global namespace and run into potential collisions as a result